Why Does My Kusto Output Table Background Color Change to Black?
After run a query, the output table's background becomes black. It only happens to this specific query in table A. If I try the same query to table B, the background color doesn't change.Anyone know why?
Table A
| extend new_column  = columnc
Output table becomes black
Table B
| extend new_column  = columnc
Output table background color unchanged, stays white

these documents may answer your question, depending on which client you're using:

Kusto Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer#table-row-colors

Web Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-results-grid#color-results-by-error-level


